# Remove HTTP headers from Prometheus in Zabbix

Tags: regex, http-headers, zabbix

I have a server that has a Nginx VTS module installed on it, which outputs metrics in prometheus format.

When I try to actively check `web.page.get` via Zabbix I get the HTTP header and then the data in the format below:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: nginx

Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2020 09:16:20 GMT

Content-Type: text/plain

Content-Length: 33769

Connection: close

Vary: Accept-Encoding



# HELP nginx_vts_info Nginx info
# TYPE nginx_vts_info gauge
nginx_vts_info{hostname="example",version="1.18.0"} 1
# HELP nginx_vts_start_time_seconds Nginx start time
# TYPE nginx_vts_start_time_seconds gauge
nginx_vts_start_time_seconds 1600367492.145

# snip output...
```

I wrote a regular expression that removes the header but only outputs the first line:

```
# \n\s?\n(.*)

# HELP nginx_vts_info Nginx info
```

[image: Regex]

How do I rewrite the expression so that the header is removed and the rest of the data is available?

Comment: Try `\n\s?\n([\s\S]*)`

Comment: @Liju Thanks a million. Worked for me!

Give an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below regex

```regex
\n\s?\n([\s\S]*)
```

in regex `.` wont check newlines unless specific flags set. hence in your example, only the first line was returned. so rewriting it to include newlines as well will help.